# redirecting all files in a directory to fetch ?id=

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have this in my htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Which is great for redirecting all files from example:
login.php to /login or apply.php to /apply

Now how do I get the ID from ALL files in my directory to redirect example:

```
RewriteRule ^home/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ home.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^home/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/home/?$ home.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

That takes home.php?id=72 and redirects it to /home/72 - (THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE BUT FOR ALL FILES)

But at current I am having to add the same 2 lines in my htaccess for every file that queries the id=$.

Any help would be appreciated massively.

Comment: This is impressive. You are using rewrite rules that use matching patterns for your "id's" but you are not able to apply the same logic to the file name base? Not even with many many examples for this you can see here on SO? Could it be that you do not really understand how your own rules work? If so, then do yourself a favor and find out about that! You need to understand what you are doing!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words of encouragement. Everyone has to learn somewhere and I am not an expert that's why I took to the forum. But nice to know I can rely on you anytime I'm struggling, appreciating you taking the time out to comment (y) Peace brother

Comment: You appear to be frustrated about my comment. That is also interesting. Because you in no way refer to its actual content, my constructive hint to you. Certainly everyone has to learn, we all do all the time. But we primarily do so by looking at what we already have and trying to apply the same thing to new tasks. Your question shows no such effort. You simply ask for a solution to copy. Please read about what questions to ask here and what preconditions hae to be fulfilled to ask: a major one is that you have to try yourself and show that effort in your question. You did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are rewriting try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Please try the edit and remove/comment your previous rules.

Comment: Really appreciate your help but it's still not working. I can still visit the appended url now but receive 500 error on visiting ?id= 

:(

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood what is your original url and what is your required url please reply in comment?

Comment: What you have typed seems to be correct, but it's not working. my url would be applications.php?id=72
with the above code I can visit /applications but I have 500 error when I go to /applications/72  - Does that make sense?

Comment: I've edited my rule one more time and I am going to check it on my side too until then please try it in your local setup.

Comment: Same thing is happening.. I can visit /applications but as soon as i visit /applications/429 I get a 500 server error

Comment: Glad could help i am not a genius i am also a leaner like yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. I've been struggling to get it to function and had such a sloppy htaccess file. Glad you could finally clean it up for me!